# Get program id/address from Solana transaction data (solana/web3.js)

Tags: node.js, solana, solana-web3js

I want to determine whether a transaction has interacted with a specific program id "cndyAnrLdpjq1Ssp1z8xxDsB8dxe7u4HL5Nxi2K5WXZ" (being the Candy Machine program address).

I'm using @solana/web3.js to get the below (bottom of post) Candy Machine mint transaction data using connection.getTransaction(txn.signature).

How can I determine whether the transaction interacted with the Candy Machine program?

I have tried digging into transaction.meta.innerInstructions, but I can't work out how to translate this into program id addresses.

```
[
  {
    'accounts': '2',
    'data': '3Bxs4h24hBtQy9rw',
    'programIdIndex': '8'
  },{
    'accounts': '2',
    'data': '9krTDU2LzCSUJuVZ',
    'programIdIndex': '8'
  },{
    'accounts': '2',
    'data': 'SYXsBSQy3GeifSEQSGvTbrPNposbSAiSoh1YA85wcvGKSnYg',
    'programIdIndex': '8'
  },
...etc.
]
```

*Note: I realise I could just search for the program address within "logMessages" string, but that's cheating somewhat and I'm trying to learn how this all works.*

Example mint transaction data which DOES interact with the Candy Machine program:

```
{
  blockTime: 1640299576,
  meta: {
    err: null,
    fee: 10000,
    innerInstructions: [ [Object], [Object] ],
    logMessages: [
      'Program 11111111111111111111111111111111 invoke [1]',
      'Program 11111111111111111111111111111111 success',
      'Program TokenkegQfeZyiNwAJbNbGKPFXCWuBvf9Ss623VQ5DA invoke [1]',
      'Program log: Instruction: InitializeMint',
      'Program TokenkegQfeZyiNwAJbNbGKPFXCWuBvf9Ss623VQ5DA consumed 2390 of 200000 compute units',
      'Program TokenkegQfeZyiNwAJbNbGKPFXCWuBvf9Ss623VQ5DA success',
      'Program ATokenGPvbdGVxr1b2hvZbsiqW5xWH25efTNsLJA8knL invoke [1]',
      'Program log: Transfer 2039280 lamports to the associated token account',
      'Program 11111111111111111111111111111111 invoke [2]',
      'Program 11111111111111111111111111111111 success',
      'Program log: Allocate space for the associated token account',
      'Program 11111111111111111111111111111111 invoke [2]',
      'Program 11111111111111111111111111111111 success',
      'Program log: Assign the associated token account to the SPL Token program',
      'Program 11111111111111111111111111111111 invoke [2]',
      'Program 11111111111111111111111111111111 success',
      'Program log: Initialize the associated token account',
      'Program TokenkegQfeZyiNwAJbNbGKPFXCWuBvf9Ss623VQ5DA invoke [2]',
      'Program log: Instruction: InitializeAccount',
      'Program TokenkegQfeZyiNwAJbNbGKPFXCWuBvf9Ss623VQ5DA consumed 3449 of 179576 compute units',
      'Program TokenkegQfeZyiNwAJbNbGKPFXCWuBvf9Ss623VQ5DA success',
      'Program ATokenGPvbdGVxr1b2hvZbsiqW5xWH25efTNsLJA8knL consumed 24522 of 200000 compute units',
      'Program ATokenGPvbdGVxr1b2hvZbsiqW5xWH25efTNsLJA8knL success',
      'Program TokenkegQfeZyiNwAJbNbGKPFXCWuBvf9Ss623VQ5DA invoke [1]',
      'Program log: Instruction: MintTo',
      'Program TokenkegQfeZyiNwAJbNbGKPFXCWuBvf9Ss623VQ5DA consumed 2879 of 200000 compute units',
      'Program TokenkegQfeZyiNwAJbNbGKPFXCWuBvf9Ss623VQ5DA success',
      'Program cndyAnrLdpjq1Ssp1z8xxDsB8dxe7u4HL5Nxi2K5WXZ invoke [1]',
      'Program 11111111111111111111111111111111 invoke [2]',
      'Program 11111111111111111111111111111111 success',
      'Program metaqbxxUerdq28cj1RbAWkYQm3ybzjb6a8bt518x1s invoke [2]',
      'Program log: Instruction: Create Metadata Accounts',
      'Program log: Transfer 5616720 lamports to the new account',
      'Program 11111111111111111111111111111111 invoke [3]',
      'Program 11111111111111111111111111111111 success',
      'Program log: Allocate space for the account',
      'Program 11111111111111111111111111111111 invoke [3]',
      'Program 11111111111111111111111111111111 success',
      'Program log: Assign the account to the owning program',
      'Program 11111111111111111111111111111111 invoke [3]',
      'Program 11111111111111111111111111111111 success',
      'Program metaqbxxUerdq28cj1RbAWkYQm3ybzjb6a8bt518x1s consumed 23040 of 176519 compute units',
      'Program metaqbxxUerdq28cj1RbAWkYQm3ybzjb6a8bt518x1s success',
      'Program metaqbxxUerdq28cj1RbAWkYQm3ybzjb6a8bt518x1s invoke [2]',
      'Program log: Instruction: Create Master Edition',
      'Program log: Transfer 2853600 lamports to the new account',
      'Program 11111111111111111111111111111111 invoke [3]',
      'Program 11111111111111111111111111111111 success',
      'Program log: Allocate space for the account',
      'Program 11111111111111111111111111111111 invoke [3]',
      'Program 11111111111111111111111111111111 success',
      'Program log: Assign the account to the owning program',
      'Program 11111111111111111111111111111111 invoke [3]',
      'Program 11111111111111111111111111111111 success',
      'Program log: Setting mint authority',
      'Program TokenkegQfeZyiNwAJbNbGKPFXCWuBvf9Ss623VQ5DA invoke [3]',
      'Program log: Instruction: SetAuthority',
      'Program TokenkegQfeZyiNwAJbNbGKPFXCWuBvf9Ss623VQ5DA consumed 2019 of 126852 compute units',
      'Program TokenkegQfeZyiNwAJbNbGKPFXCWuBvf9Ss623VQ5DA success',
      'Program log: Setting freeze authority',
      'Program TokenkegQfeZyiNwAJbNbGKPFXCWuBvf9Ss623VQ5DA invoke [3]',
      'Program log: Instruction: SetAuthority',
      'Program TokenkegQfeZyiNwAJbNbGKPFXCWuBvf9Ss623VQ5DA consumed 2021 of 122246 compute units',
      'Program TokenkegQfeZyiNwAJbNbGKPFXCWuBvf9Ss623VQ5DA success',
      'Program log: Finished setting freeze authority',
      'Program metaqbxxUerdq28cj1RbAWkYQm3ybzjb6a8bt518x1s consumed 28978 of 148307 compute units',
      'Program metaqbxxUerdq28cj1RbAWkYQm3ybzjb6a8bt518x1s success',
      'Program metaqbxxUerdq28cj1RbAWkYQm3ybzjb6a8bt518x1s invoke [2]',
      'Program log: Instruction: Update Metadata Accounts',
      'Program metaqbxxUerdq28cj1RbAWkYQm3ybzjb6a8bt518x1s consumed 7238 of 116624 compute units',
      'Program metaqbxxUerdq28cj1RbAWkYQm3ybzjb6a8bt518x1s success',
      'Program cndyAnrLdpjq1Ssp1z8xxDsB8dxe7u4HL5Nxi2K5WXZ consumed 94165 of 200000 compute units',
      'Program cndyAnrLdpjq1Ssp1z8xxDsB8dxe7u4HL5Nxi2K5WXZ success'
    ],
    postBalances: [
         636708880,    1461600,
           2039280,    4572720,
      737969768141,    5616720,
           2853600,    1009200,
                 1, 1089991680,
        9286574880,    1141440,
           1169280,  898174080,
           1141440
    ],
    postTokenBalances: [ [Object] ],
    preBalances: [
         898690080,          0,
                 0,    4572720,
      737719768141,          0,
                 0,    1009200,
                 1, 1089991680,
        9286574880,    1141440,
           1169280,  898174080,
           1141440
    ],
    preTokenBalances: [],
    rewards: [],
    status: { Ok: null }
  },
  slot: 112965987,
  transaction: {
    message: Message {
      header: [Object],
      accountKeys: [Array],
      recentBlockhash: 'B2EuNArBL5XL1coHVZY53Gob7FxrqUxA77DsBRPJwVyd',
      instructions: [Array],
      indexToProgramIds: [Map]
    },
    signatures: [
      '5E8VZSRhfUffRuZFUwoGmDsV1hMzqq2zD5sV6hZPAVFQizXa5SeEpYKw5RWfSMX4bsxB8GyELfPJhYaeLxUn5yjT',
      '4ZaC8PSqBH95Yk8X8aSiea6dEBwostzaf9WxQQKdNNKs4VjGGUJDYw8iAJsp9SxwkgUjM68kZuD4xK1Yxwnq4jM1'
    ]
  }
}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

https://solana-labs.github.io/solana-web3.js/modules.html#TransactionResponse

The transaction object is organized to contain a list of all the accounts (programs are accounts) which it interacts with in `tx.transaction.message.accountKeys`

for any instruction in `tx.meta.innerInstructions` you can find a `programIdIndex` (`tx.meta.innerInstructions.instructions[0].programIdIndex`) which refers to the index in the accounts array of the program which the instruction interacts with

so you can find the programId of a specific transaction like so,

```
let accs = tx.transaction.message.accountKeys; // get all accs of all ixs
for (let inner_ixs of tx.meta.innerInstructions) {
    let first_ix = inner_ixs.instructions[0] // ix of interest 
    let program_id = accs[first_ix.programIdIndex].toString(); 
            
    if (program_id != CANDY_PROGRAM_ID) { continue } 
    // ...
```